# Xamarin iOS - PrepareForSegue compile error

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, segue

I'm having issues when trying to implement PrepareForSegue ... it can't find a suitable method to override (and/or NSStoryboardSegue and NSObject) ... Thoughts on the following?

[image]

Do I need to add a "using" include statement or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The right signature is:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
}
```

Comment: Closer ... now it's complaining about NSObject (but seems to be able to find UIStoryboardSegue) ... is there something I need to include (i.e. "using") ... or is NSObject supposed to be something different?

Comment: you need: `using Foundation;`